# Why I can't read file?

Tags: java, file

hi i want to make simple game. but before i create game logic, i got a problem. as i mentioned on the title. i can't read jpg file. i got this error message "Can't read input file!". I know it's from e.getMessage(). But that's all. I really don't know WHY this happened. In the missilegame package, there is 3 jpg files already.

so, here is code.

```
package missilegame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class GraphicObject {
BufferedImage img = null;
int x, y = 0;

public GraphicObject(String name) {
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(name));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void update() {
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event, int x, int y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}

class Missile extends GraphicObject {
    boolean launched = false;

    public Missile(String name) {
        super(name);
        y = -200;
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        if (launched)
            y -= 1;
        if (y < -100) {
            launched = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event, int x, int y) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            launched = true;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
}

class Enemy extends GraphicObject {
    int dx = -10;

    public Enemy(String name) {
        super(name);
        x = 500;
        y = 0;
    }

    public void update() {
        x += dx;
        if (x < 0) {
            dx = +10;
        }
        if (x > 500)
            dx = -10;
    }

}

class SpaceShip extends GraphicObject {
    public SpaceShip(String name) {
        super(name);
        x = 150;
        y = 350;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            x -= 10;
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            x += 10;
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            y -= 10;
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            y += 10;
        }
    }
}

class MyGamePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    Enemy enemy;
    SpaceShip spaceShip;
    Missile missile;

    public MyGamePanel() {
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.requestFocus();
        setFocusable(true);

        enemy = new Enemy("./enemy.jpg");
        spaceShip = new SpaceShip("./spaceship.jpg");
        missile = new Missile("./missile.jpg");
        class MyThread extends Thread {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    enemy.update();
                    spaceShip.update();
                    missile.update();
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        Thread t = new MyThread();
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        enemy.draw(g);
        spaceShip.draw(g);
        missile.draw(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        spaceShip.keyPressed(e);
        missile.keyPressed(e,spaceShip.x,spaceShip.y);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

}

public class MissileGame extends JFrame {
    public MissileGame() {
        setTitle("MY Game");
        add(new MyGamePanel());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MissileGame();
    }
```

}

Comment: oh i forgot that. thx

Comment: Which file fails? Does it actually exist on your hard drive?

Comment: make sure the file path is getting passed correctly. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249049/scanner-cant-find-my-file-to-read-java-with-eclipse/26249136#26249136

Comment: I erase System.exit(0) line. and checked. All files are fail. and these files are exactly exist

Comment: run file.exists() as an assert at the top, propably this file has wrong path.

Comment: i add

File file= new File(name);
System.out.println(file.exists());

and get false. as you guys mentioned file path have a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the missilegame package, there is 3 jpg files already.

But your code doesn't read from the missilegame package. It reads a file in the current directory, on the file system. The current directory is the directory from where the `java` command is executed. And your files are not (necessarily) on the file system. They're resources embedded in the application, that should be loaded with the class loader.

Replace

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File(name));
```

by

```
img = ImageIO.read(GraphicObject.class.getResourceAsStream("/missilegame/" + name));
```

and replace `"./enemy.jpg"` by `"enemy.jpg"`.